# How to convert select box into radio in checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change credit card type option into radio button. for that i have found file ccsave.phtml

Here is the code of select box that appear in checkout page.

```
<div class="input-box">
            <select id="<?php echo $_code ?>_cc_type" name="payment[cc_type]" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Credit Card Type')) ?>" class="required-entry validate-cc-type-select">
                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--') ?></option>
            <?php $_ccType = $this->getInfoData('cc_type') ?>
            <?php foreach ($this->getCcAvailableTypes() as $_typeCode => $_typeName): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $_typeCode ?>"<?php if($_typeCode==$_ccType): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>><?php echo $_typeName ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>
        </div>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
<div class="input-box">                
    <?php $_ccType = $this->getInfoData('cc_type') ?>
    <?php foreach ($this->getCcAvailableTypes() as $_typeCode => $_typeName): ?>
        <input type="radio"  name="payment[cc_type]" value="<?php echo $_typeCode ?>" />               
    <?php endforeach ?>       
</div>
```

This will render as radio. for validation you need to add your validation logic